# Git failed with ENOMEM

Tags: git, enomem

`git pull` causes `fatal: Out of memory, getdelim failed`
I've tried to `git pc`, re-installed git. I have enough free space in the RAM (more than 6GB) and something like 8GB free in the swap.
I use git version 2.5.5 on the Linux, Fedora 4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64

Do you any ideas?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here to diagnose the issue. At the very least, you should be providing information about the version of Git you're on, the OS (and which shell, if Windows), and details about the repo that you can provide.

Comment: usually ram errors are not due to you not having enough ram, it's due to the 32 bit process not being able to allocate more than 2gb of ram. Are you using a particularly large repo or something? Usually the fix is to use a 64bit version of the program that is causing issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could this happen when reading a socket with a error ENOMEM return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072292/how-could-this-happen-when-reading-a-socket-with-a-error-enomem-return)